# WP_Query arguments: Loop through custom post type - get all entries except excluded meta_key?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, meta-query

Can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'wr_event', // my custom post type
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // show all posts 
    'meta_query' => array(
          array(
             'key' => 'event_announced', // a custom field either "on" or "off"
             'value' => 'on',
             'compare'  => 'NOT IN'
             )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

So all I want to do is loop through all `wr_events` but if an event has the custom field `event_announced` (a checkbox) checked I'd like to exclude it.

Ideas? I tried setting "on" or "off" for the `value` and tried different solutions for `compare`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query will select posts that have a value in the key `event_announced` which does not equal `on`. What I think you want is `NOT EXISTS`, and you can omit `value`, since you are querying for posts that don't have the key, hence, it will have no value. Note that `NOT EXISTS` is only available in WordPress 3.5+